# Multiple comparisons (i.e., cluster 1 vs cluster 2+3), how to adjust p-value

Tags: clustering, p-value, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I am analyzing the differences in mean of a continuos variable between 3 clusters. I used anova (after testing whether it has a parametric distribution) and obtained p-value lower than 0.05. As post-hoc tests I first used Tukey test to see the differences in pairwise cluster comparisons. However, now I want to see whether there is a statistical significant difference between cluster 1 vs cluster 2 + 3. Can I still do this with Tukey? Can I merge cluster 2 + 3 and do t-test to compare with cluster 1? In that case how should I adjust the p-value? (I understand the Bonferroni adjustment would be dividing by all possible pairwise combinations but what about grouped combinations?)

Thank you